# Flask deployed with twistd: Failed to load application: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, flask, twisted, daemon, twisted.web

I am trying to [deploy my Twisted application using .tac files and twistd](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html)

I tried to deploy it with the command line:

`twistd -y service.tac`

I have the error:

...

```
application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
```

`--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 450, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 411, in loadApplication
    passphrase)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 224, in loadValueFromFile
    eval(codeObj, d, d)
  File "service.tac", line 54, in <module>`

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 61, in isabs
    return s.startswith('/')`

`exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

`Failed to load application: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

My service.tac file is:

`from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)`

Answer (score 0):

Your application import_name can't be identified properly in *.tac file. If you create flask application in *.py file and import it in *.tac it will work just fine.

But you also need another list of [instructions](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html) for deploying Flask application via twistd. Minimal example looks like this:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.internet import reactor

from my_flask_module import my_flask_app

application = service.Application('myapplication')
service = service.IServiceCollection(application)

flask_resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), my_flask_app)
flask_site = Site(flask_resource)
internet.TCPServer(8000, flask_site).setServiceParent(service)
```